# Calling the value of an HTML element as an onclick of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select box that calls a function on change.

```
<select name ="selectBox" class="select_box" onchange="getVal(this)">
```

I would like to call this value again upon the change of a radio choice.

```
<input type="radio" name="orderBy" value="desc" class="radio_sort" onchange="getVal(this)"> Descending<br>
<input type="radio" name="orderBy" value="asc" class="radio_sort" onchange="getVal(this)"> Ascending<br>
```

This doesn't work. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by `call this value again`

Comment: When I pick a different radio button, the function that was called in the select box is called again with the value of the select box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than passing `this` you may as well just always print or do whatever you need to do with the select box when you run the function. (I have added an id to it for this example).

Unless you need the function to perform different things based on content, passing `this` is unnecessary in your context.

```js
function getVal()
{
    var select = document.getElementById("selectBox");
    console.log(select.value);
}
```

```html
<select id="selectBox" name ="selectBox" class="select_box" onchange="getVal()">
  <option>yes</option>
  <option>no</option>  
</select>

<input type="radio" name="test" onChange="getVal()"/> First
<input type="radio" name="test" onChange="getVal()"/> Secon
```

Comment: This is correct, unless you are using getVal() for multiple html elements.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. Will accept the asnwer in two minutes

Comment: @Acidic I think you mean multiple select elements, but yes, this is applicable only when you're wanting a known select.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a "minimal" question, as per [Hep center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)... And probably not "complete".

But try this:

```
<input type="radio" name="orderBy" value="desc" class="radio_sort" onchange="getVal( $( '[name=\"selectbox\"]' )"> Descending<br>
<input type="radio" name="orderBy" value="asc" class="radio_sort" onchange="getVal $( '[name=\"selectbox\"]' )"> Ascending<br>
```

The trick is to provide the right element as argument to the function.
;)